# NDSolve Step Size Effectively Zero

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve a PDE for a function of 2 variables. The most accurate parameterizations of this equation are very unwieldy and involve numerous piecewise elements, and so right now I'm trying to solve an approximate form. I'm getting step size effectively 0 errors, unless I increase the starting step size, in which case the solution I get is clearly unphysical. Since this is an astrophysics problem, I'm working over many orders of magnitude, which I suspect might be part of the issue.

Code:

```
z[x_]:= 2458.31 - 100.087 x + 1.23213 x^2 - 0.0046743 x^3

lamavg[t_] := Min[1, 0.01 + 0.07 z[t]];

Ufit2[M_,t_]:=0.50519 + 3.127*10^10/M^2 - 274337./M + 2.12127*10^-10 M           
-1.92858*10^-20 M^2 - 6.20762*10^-11 t;

fixedM[x_] := 
0.00006192808740866853/
591.5967816994163 (32.59434080693661 - 2.0297457454952188*^-7 x + 
1.2887918124478197*^-15 x^2 - 2.5861699533219344*^-25 x^3 + 
1.941139394441828*^-35 x^4 - 5.134757798851362*^-46 x^5)

DifEq = D[P[M, t],t] == -M l /sol^2 D[(1 - e)/e                                  
lamavg[t] *3.93242 * Ufit2[M, t] P[M, t], M] //. {e -> 
0.1,l -> 1.26 * 10^(31), sol -> 3*^8 };

soln = NDSolve[{DifEq, P[M, 8.15240949872944*^8] == 
1.629652976233948/M, P[1*^5 .263, t] == fixedM[t]}, P[M,
t], {t, 1000, 8.15240949872944*^8}, {M, 1*10^5.263, 10000000000}, 
Method -> { "StiffnessSwitching", "NonstiffTest" -> False}]
```

In terms of what I expect, this is a black hole mass function over the evolution of the universe, so P shouldn't fall off as time decreases, and there should be a difference of several orders of magnitude (especially at large t) between the low and high mass end.

Also I shortened the interval because the part here is the most important part, but ideally I would be able to continue the integration up to t of about 10 billion (not important at the moment though).

Thanks!

Comment: "I'm working over many orders of magnitude" - is there really no choice of units that will give quantities of comparable size?

Comment: What is the definition for `fixedM`

Comment: Do you have two accounts?  You should not need the review of others to edit your own question.

Comment: Can the time boundary be moved to one of the extremes of t

Comment: Please look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to have your accounts merged.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on merging accounts.
@ J.M. There actually is a change of units I can use, working on that right now--involves reorganizing some data so may take a bit (I suppose that's why I hadn't tried it yet).
@Young The backward evolution from the t point chosen is the important part, and restricting to that (just dropping all larger t points) does indeed help some, thanks!

Comment: Should any parentheses be added to the functions to ensure the right order of operation? Particularly `Unfit2`

Comment: all exponents apply to the variables right next to them, not to the coefficients as well. I'm pretty sure that's how Mathematica reads what I have written though, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I was referring to the division `/`

Comment: What do you expect the range of `P` to be?

Comment: on the scale of 10^-3 at largest, although I'm interested in its behavior to lower scales too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This evaluates without errors:

```
z[x_] := 2458.31 - 100.087 x + 1.23213 x^2 - 0.0046743 x^3

lamavg[t_] := Min[1, 0.01 + 0.07 z[t]]

Ufit2[M_, t_] := 0.50519 + 3.127*10^10/M^2 - 274337/M + 2.12127*10^-10 M - 
                 1.92858*10^-20 M^2 - 6.20762*10^-11 t;

e = 1/100;
l = (126/100)*10^(31);
sol = 3*^8;

DifEq = D[P[M, t],t] == -M l/ sol^2 D[(1 - e)/e lamavg[t]*3.93242*Ufit2[M, t] P[M, t], M];

fixedM[x_] := 0.00006192808740866853/ 591.5967816994163 
   (32.59434080693661 - 2.0297457454952188*^-7 x + 
    1.2887918124478197*^-15 x^2 - 2.5861699533219344*^-25 x^3 + 
    1.941139394441828*^-35 x^4 - 5.134757798851362*^-46 x^5)

soln = NDSolve[{
   DifEq,
   P[M, 8.15240949872944*^8] == 1.629652976233948/M,
   P[0.263*^5, t] == fixedM[t]},
  P[M, t], {M, 0.263*^5, 10000000000}, {t, 1000, 8.15240949872944*^8},
   Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]

Plot3D[P[M, t] /. soln, {M, 0.263*^5, 10000000000}, {t, 1000, 8.15240949872944*^8}]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you meant to try `Plot3D[P[M, t] /. soln,...]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 ... oops ... your right

Comment: What about the rest of the interval?  (I can get it to work with some trickiness, but your approach would be simpler.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 The OP said that I could set max `t` to equal the boundary condition of `8.15240949872944*^8`

Comment: This is about the right scale but not really the behavior I'm expecting...blackholes shouldn't just disappear!

Comment: No it looks like they all evaporate when the universe is about 800 million years old (Hawking radiation is not part of this model).

Comment: @basementDweller Thanks!

Comment: yes I was surprised to see that Mathematica interprets 1*^5.263 differently from 1*10^5.263, while I thought those were supposed to be the same thing... also @Michael E2 thanks, good point